# Deleted-table used in instead of update trigger

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I got the following code ( no chance to ask the person who wrote it ) and don't see the need of the `inner join on deleted`. Do I miss something?
I thought, the deleted-table is used in `instead-of-delete triggers`. In `instead-of-inserted triggers` [it's empty everytime](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms175089%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), isn't it in `instead-of-update triggers`?

```
CREATE TRIGGER "someTrigger" ON "dbo"."someView"
INSTEAD OF UPDATE
AS
BEGIN           
    INSERT INTO "someOtherTable"
    ( 
        "id"
        , "startTime"
        , "endTime"
        , "duration"
        , "resourceId"
        , "resourceLocked"
        , "timeLocked"
        , "groupPrefix"
    )
    SELECT 
        "id"                = i."id"
        , "startTime"       = i."startTime"
        , "endTime"         = i."endTime"
        , "duration"        = ISNULL( i."duration", 0 )
        , "resourceId"      = i."resourceId"
        , "resourceLocked"  = ISNULL( i."resourceLocked", 0 )
        , "timeLocked"      = ISNULL( i."timeLocked", 0 )
        , "groupPrefix"     = N'gp'
    FROM inserted AS i
    INNER JOIN deleted AS d
        ON d."id" = i."id"
    WHERE ( i."jobType" != 3 )
       OR ( i."jobType"  = 3 AND i."startTime" != d."startTime" );

END;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an update trigger, both [`inserted` and `deleted`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx) are populated. `inserted` contains the new row values, `deleted` contains the old row values, i.e. the values from before the `UPDATE` statement executed.

Here, it seems to be being used in the `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE ( i."jobType" != 3 )
   OR ( i."jobType"  = 3 AND i."startTime" != d."startTime" );
```

So, if `jobType` is 3, we only do the insert if the `startTime` has been changed.

---

It should be noted that correlating the rows between `inserted` and `deleted` is only possible if at least one key's column(s) are not subject to update. Here, `id` appears to be a key. *Hopefully* that `id` column isn't subject to update or else this trigger may misbehave when such updates occur.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't know that `deleted` is also populated in an update trigger.